# INDEX/MATCH/MATCH Python Equivalent

Tags: python, excel, indexing

I am looking for the best way to index through tables similar to that shown below. The user will be inputting an X and Y value, and the matching index would be stored in a variable.

EX: X = A, Y = 1, newVar = 100

Table Referenced:

[image]

I need to import 20+ tables from excel. The tables will be updated every 6-12 months. I have yet to try anything, as I have not found any questions that relate to my exact issue. I have found plenty of information on INDEX/MATCH equivalent, when searching through a vertical table.

Given that this is a 2-dimensional table, should I be using Pandas? Is there a better module to use?

Thank you for your time reading and patience with someone new!

Comment: Yes you should be using pandas and look at `loc`.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure where to look in Pandas for this.